# Driver not detecting child browser

Tags: browser, selenium-webdriver, window, driver

Can any one solve the below query?

Page title: Example 1
Example 1 contains one button named as button1, when you click button1 it will open a co-browser/child browser.
Page title: co-browser
Unitil you close the co browser you can not navigate to Example 1. Co-browser has two button "close" and "Print"

I need to close the co-browser. I have tried with the below code but it is not working:

```
    //store instance of main window first using below code
    String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle(); 

    // Switch to new window opened
    for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }

    // Perform the actions on new window
    driver.close();

    //switch back to main window using this code
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of that co-browser.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below screenshot.

I want to close the "ePOS fair obtaining Statement" this browser.

Below are the details:

Comment: Screenshot is not visible. Please add the image properly.